# parse data to vc in swift 4 always nil

Tags: swift4

i want to parse data from one VC to antoher to open a webview with the given data as URL String. The data comes from a tableview. In the table view i have a button with a function to open the segue.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFArchivTableViewCell? {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PFCell") as! PFArchivTableViewCell?

    cell?.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(someAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    cell?.button.accessibilityHint = object?.object(forKey: "calameoURL") as? String} return cell
```

Then i use a function for the button:

```
 @objc func someAction(sender: UIButton) {
    let PFurlString = sender.accessibilityHint!
    print ("URL in the cell: \(PFurlString)")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPFArchivUrl", sender: AnyObject.self)

}
```

and the prepare for segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showPFArchivUrl" {
    let destination = segue.destination as? ArchivWebViewController
    print ("button pressed")
    destination?.dataFromFirst = "Hello World"
    destination?.PFurlString? = PFurlString!

    }

}
```

The Problem is: the passed string in the *ArchivWebViewController* "Hello World" is available, but the given variable "PFurlString" is always nil. Has anyone an idea to get this variable on the other viewcontroller?

thanks a lot for the answer. i have change the following lines:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PFCell") as! PFArchivTableViewCell
cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(someAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    cell.button.accessibilityHint = object?.object(forKey: "calameoURL") as? String
```

in the func for the button i get the value for the *accessibilityHint* in my print statement.

but in *prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)*  the value is always nil

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showPFArchivUrl" {
    let destination = segue.destination as! ArchivWebViewController
print ("URL: \(PFurlString)")
        destination.PFurlString = PFurlString

    }
```

Comment: You are using too many exclamation and question marks. For example the syntax `as! PFArchivTableViewCell?` (force downcast an optional to an optional) is pointless. Remove the `?`. It's recommended to force unwrap optionals which must not fail at runtime because they discover a design error. With optional down casting nothing happens and you don't know why. Force unwrap the destination view controller:  `let destination = segue.destination as! ArchivWebViewController`. If you get a crash there is something wrong with the segue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a local PFurlString in @objc func someAction(sender: UIButton). IDK, where you get the PFurlString but try replacing

```
    let PFurlString = sender.accessibilityHint!
```

with

```
    PFurlString = sender.accessibilityHint!
```

Make sure you have a class variable of something like **var PFurlString : String?**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with a variable in which you save the data of the URL. After you have presented the new view controller you can call this class in it and get the value of the variable and the as a result the url